# JSP struts

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags

How would I assign a variable within scriplet code in JSP <%>  and then use struts logic tags to do stuff based on the value of the variable assigned in the scriplet code block?

I have tried using struts:logic equal and greaterthan to no avail....

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do (if I understand you correct) is basically this:

```
<% String foo = "Test"; %>
<bean:write name="foo" />
```

Which, as you already know, doesn't work. That would give an error like this:

> Cannot find bean foo in any scope

What I usually do, is to put my data in the page scope like this:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("foo", "Test"); %>
<bean:write name="foo" />
```

(This is for Struts 1.1. Newer versions may provide a better way to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

In scriptlet:

```
<%
   request.setAttribute("customerName", "rajesh");
%>
```

And you can check in struts logic tags like,

```
<logic:match name="customerName" value="Vijay"></logic:match>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess u find this:

scriptlet code u have to  write Java code on JSP

```
<%int var=1; %>in jsp its declaration ( <%! int i = 0; %> )
```

The expression element can contain any expression that is valid according to the Java Language Specification but you cannot use a semicolon to end an expression

```
<p>   Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%></p>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in Struts2 using tags. for Example:

```
<c:set var="contains" value="true" />
```

logic can be tested:

```
<c:if test="%{#variable=='String 1'}">
    This is String 1
</c:if>
```

other sources:
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-if-elseif-else-tag-example/

Required taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```